# MonoGame Xna how can I import an animated model from Maya

Tags: c#, xna

I have been trying to get an animated model from Maya to Monogame and Xna but all i get is a rigid model with no animation. I converted the model to fbx and then to xnb files but nothing is working. Found some hints to the SkinnedEffect but I cant seem to make it work. I found some samples of of rigged models but I get an error when i try to open the project in Visual Studios. Cans somebody help me with this issue.

Comment: Screenshots / a more in-depth look at what you have tried would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[There is an example](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model) how to implement model animation logic for XNA game.
Try install same version of XNA and VS if you got en error. I have XNA 4 and VS2010 and I successfully has opened this project.

If you need more theory look for it on the Internet.
if you need an example I can give you my own (not totally completed) example with importers and processors for .obj and .smd models included.